# Issue while encrypting password at clientside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encryption, browser

I am encrypting user Id and Password when after user clicks on Submit button.
Then At server side, I am decrypting it and then verifying it in database

For some users / browsers, when user clicks on submit, the User ID and password is not getting encrypted and being send as a plain text. in this case, at server side, when my C# code is trying to decrypt it, throwing an exception (because its not encrypted but a plain text)

This is happening at rare case as below

1. Only for few users
2. Only when user clicks on "forgot password".  In this case, while creating new password (Here we ask user to type password 2 times, against label Password and Confirm password)
3. when user log in (where we ask user to type user if and password) encryption works perfectly for the same user.
4. Further, while Forgot Password, If I ask user to enable javascript debugging and debug the Encryption code, it works perfectly fine

Can you help on this.
Why browser is not encrypting password in some cases as above. It does encryption when in browser debug mode, but otherwise it does not

Is there any browser settings I need to check for ?

**Other information** :-
I am using CryptoJS.AES.encrypt for encryption

Comment: Please show the code that encrypts the password. Keep in mind though, that this approach isn't prudent. There is no point to encrypt the password at the client side for two reasons - if you use HTTPS, it is already being encrypted for you, and even if you use plain HTTP - for the attacker, there is no reason to get the plain password, he would intercept the encrypted one and resend it whenever required.